# How to import data in Odoo from CSV files?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In older versions of Odoo it was possible to import data from csv file only when you were installing a module (using init).

This function is now deprecated because you need to use the data folder that updates the data every time you update the module.

The only way to import data when you install module is using xml with the attribute `noupdate="1"`.

To import data we use an ETL program that creates CSV file (create the XML file is more complex).

Does anybody know why you can not use the CSV file to import data only upon installation?

To perform bulk imports have always been used CSV. Someone has resolved, or the only way is to create XML files of thousands of tags??

Comment: Go to the list view. There you can press the "Import" button to import CSV files to that table. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I knew that already existed the function of import but I thought there was a less manual to import data .
In the case of import complex ( many files also related to them) would be useful to use the csv file with external_id within a specific module for the imports . Thank you.

Comment: OK, you are welcome. Please mark my answer as a correct answer if it was useful :)

Answer (score 3):

If you go to a list view of some model, you can see the "Import" button. Press it in order to import CSV files to that table

If you want to import data to many tables at the same time, then you need to use the external ids.

I recommend you to check this slideshow as well:

[How to Import data into OpenERP V7](http://es.slideshare.net/openobject/best-practices-on-how-to-import-data-into-openerp-cyril-morisse-consultant-audaxis)